# How to make bullets follow a rotating sinewave pattern

Tags: 2d, javascript, rotation

I am trying to replicate the wave gun from Super Metroid where the bullets fly along a sine wave path. The cool part is that you can shoot in 8 directions and the bullet still follows the sine as if the whole sine function is rotated. I've tried using a 2d transformation to allow shooting in every angle but I cant get it to work. Here my code so far ([JSFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/UbgT5/)). If you uncomment the line "Axis.dir += .02;" in the fiddle to start the rotation you'll notice that the black box doesn't follow it's axis at all.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("can"),
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
  width = canvas.width, height = canvas.height,
  Axis = { x: width / 2, y: height / 3, dir: 0, vx: 0, vy: 0, speed: 4 },
  Sine = { x: Axis.x, y: Axis.y, angle: 0 },
  loop = function() {
      var rotatedX, rotatedY;
      // Draw
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
      ctx.fillStyle = "#F00";
      ctx.fillRect(Axis.x, Axis.y, 5, 5);
      ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
      ctx.fillRect(Sine.x, Sine.y, 10, 10);
      // Apply speed
      Axis.vx = Math.cos(Axis.dir) * Axis.speed;
      Axis.vy = Math.sin(Axis.dir) * Axis.speed;
      Axis.x += Axis.vx;
      Axis.y += Axis.vy;
      Sine.x = Axis.x;
      Sine.y = Axis.y + (Math.sin(Sine.angle) * 30);
      // Apply rotation
      rotatedX = Sine.x * Math.cos(Axis.dir) - Sine.y * Math.sin(Axis.dir);
      rotatedY = Sine.x * Math.sin(Axis.dir) + Sine.y * Math.cos(Axis.dir);
      Sine.x = rotatedX;
      Sine.y = rotatedY;
      Sine.angle += .03;
      Axis.dir += .02;
      // Keep drawn stuff on the screen
      if (Axis.x > width && Axis.vx > 0) Axis.x = 0;
      if (Axis.x < 0 && Axis.vx < 0) Axis.x = width;
      if (Axis.y > height && Axis.vy > 0) Axis.y = 0;
      if (Axis.y < 0 && Axis.vy < 0) Axis.y = height;
      window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  }
loop();
```

Comment: How do you do it without the time?

Comment: Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UbgT5/1/

Comment: This is very pretty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually supposed to be simple.
There is an invisible anchor bullet moving like a normal game bullet would in a straight line (implementation not included).

You have the angle `alpha` in which the anchor bullet is moving and its position `px` & `py`.
You also have the `amplitude` (how far does the sine wave expands) and it's `frequency` (how fast does it go up and down).

You also need the `time` to determine where the actual bullet is now.

To compute the position of the sine wave bullet, use this:

```
beta = alpha + PI / 2.0.; // offset angle by 90 degrees, only run once : doesn't change
// Loop
current_distance = amplitude * sin(time * frequency); // Inside loop
bullet.x = px + cos(beta) * current_distance;
bullet.y = py + sin(beta) * current_distance;
// Done
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me figure it out, didn't even need to use time. I guess I was just overthinking the math a bit :)